# pdf prepare form modular

Tags: pdf, itext, adobe, acrobat

I have a few documents that all look the same initially, but then have different content in the middle of the document.

Is there a way to make a base template pdf, and then tell a pdf to use it as the base and then add additional template data to the result.
i.e. like a modular class system.

I am using pdf, adobe acrobat pro DC, and its Prepare Form component.
and I am usign Itext to read the template and then populate the data into a final pdf.

please remove tag if this is not related to itext, but i wondered if there was an option within itext to pull a template and then add the contents from another template.

Comment: It's a rather broad question and there are many different answers possible. We are currently developing something called "iText Dynamic Forms Solution" that might be exactly what you need, but we aren't ready to release it yet. We're working with some test customers who have already seen a POC. The next POC demo will be on September 30. The product will only be ready for release early 2017.

Comment: Thanks bruno, that sounds good, but I was looking for something I may be able to do now, with the current technologies available.

Comment: For truly dynamic forms, you can create an XFA template using Adobe Livecycle designer, [fill it with iText](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-fill-out-pdf-file-programmatically-dynamic-xfa) and flatten it with XFA Worker. For an AcroForm workaround, read [How to add a table on a form (and maybe insert a new page)?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-table-form-and-maybe-insert-new-page) or [How to continue field output on a second page?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-continue-field-output-second-page) (I'm not sure if that matches your requirement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer seems to be use livecycle designer for dynamic tempaltes.
or wait for itexts new dynamic forms.